# No "unreachable code detected"-warning in Visual Studio for new exception after return

Tags: c#

i was just wondering why Visual Studio does not show me an "unreachable code detected"-warning for the exception here:

```
private void ReturnException()
{
    return;
    throw new Exception();
    int iAmUnreachable = 0;
}
```

The warning appears only for the int.
Is there ever any circumstance in which the exception will be thrown?

Comment: It sounds more like a bug. `return; return;` will report an unreachable code warning on the second return. I'm not sure why a throw statement would be any different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The throw is unreachable but the C# compiler does not produce a warning in the case of a throw statement. This seems strange but it is by design and is documented in this [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/34625). It is to maintain backwards compatibility with older compiler versions that did not warn on this (i.e. changing it would generate many harmless warnings). Neal Gafter:

> The following types of statements are not reported as unreachable (by design)
>   - Block statements (however, statements within them may be reported unreachable)
>   - Throw statements
>   - Empty statements ;
>
> We do this because that's what the older compiler did and we don't want to "break" existing code. I think these are justified philosophically, but in any case we won't change it.